# Elixir Conform library configuration error with unrecognized type

Tags: elixir, conform

In my application, I have a below configuration for cron job scheduler

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Scheduler,
  jobs: [
    {"* * * * *", {MyApp.Core, :routine, []}}
]
```

I am using [conform](https://github.com/bitwalker/conform) library for setting up configurations for releases

Then I am running `mix conform.new` to generate `config/my_app.schema.exs` which looks like this

```
[
  extends: [],
  import: [],
  mappings: [
    "my_app.Elixir.MyApp.Scheduler.jobs": [
      commented: false,
      datatype: [
        list: {:binary, {:atom, :atom, :binary}}
      ],
      default: [
        {"* * * * *", {MyApp.Core, :routine, []}}
      ],
      doc: "Provide documentation here.",
      hidden: false,
      to: "my_app.Elixir.MyApp.Scheduler.jobs"
    ]
  ],
  transforms: [],
  validators: []
]
```

Then after this, the above file is used to generate the `.conf` file with this command `mix conform.configure` and it generates the `my_app.dev.conf` file but with the following error

```
Unable to stringify my_app.Elixir.MyApp.Scheduler.jobs, unrecognized type {:binary, {:atom, :atom, :binary}}
```

Also the `.conf` file looks like this with empty value

```
# Provide documentation for my_app.Elixir.MyApp.Scheduler.jobs here.
my_app.Elixir.MyApp.Scheduler.jobs =
```

What needs to be transformed so that the above configuration should work.

Comment: Did you try using https://github.com/quantum-elixir/quantum-core?

Comment: @AshishSingh yes this is what I am using.